# Android - new Activity is never started after calling finishAndRemoveTask method

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm testing my Android app on a Xiaomi Mi 9T Android 10 API 29.

The process is as follows:

In my activity A, I start the configuration settings activity to enable a specific permission

```
Intent intent = new Intent("<PERMISSION_ON_CONFIGURATION_SETTINGS>");
```

In the settings screen I need to dive 2 more levels of details until I can enable the permission

In my activity A there is a timer that keeps monitoring until the permission is granted:

```
public void timerStart() {
    this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (isAccessibilityEnabled()) {
                ActivityA.this.timer.cancel();
                ActivityA.this.finishAndRemoveTask();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
        }
    }, 0, 500);
}
```

It turns out that, the timer identifies that the permission was granted, the finishAndRemoveTask() method ends activity A and all configuration subactivities, but the activity B is never started. What am I doing wrong?

full code below

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn_permission;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_a);
        timerStart();
        this.btn_permission = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_permission);
        this.btn_permission.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void timerStart() {
        this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (isAccessibilityEnabled(ActivityA.this)) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    finishAndRemoveTask();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }, 0, 500);
    }

    public static boolean isAccessibilityEnabled(Context context) {
        //code
    }

}
```

Below is the sequence of screens. After granting accessibility permission, the application is completely closed, when it should go to the next activity

[image]

Right after clicking the button to grant accessibility permission the error below occurs in Logcat

```
2023-04-03 14:33:47.021  1810-4082  InputDispatcher         system_server                        E  Window handle Window{6bde395 u0 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings} has no registered input channel
2023-04-03 14:33:47.038  1810-4081  InputDispatcher         system_server                        E  Window handle Window{6bde395 u0 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings} has no registered input channel
2023-04-03 14:33:47.103  3997-5002  TraceManager            com...oglequicksearchbox:interactor  E  Duplicate trace
                                                                                                    com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.w: Starting new trace A11yEventListener_onChange when already associated with a trace: . For more help, see http://go/tiktok-tracing#fixing-duplicate-trace-issues
                                                                                                        at com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.en.f(PG:6)
                                                                                                        at com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.en.g(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.dw.d(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.libraries.search.assistant.a.g.a(PG:7)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.libraries.search.assistant.a.b.b(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at i.c.b.a.a.h(PG:4)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.bk.run(PG:14)
                                                                                                        at com.google.apps.tiktok.coroutines.g.run(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.libraries.i.y.run(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.libraries.i.g.run(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.libraries.i.ah.run(PG:5)
                                                                                                        Suppressed: com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.fy: 
                                                                                                            at tk_trace.(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                            at tk_trace.Missing root trace(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                    Caused by: com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.aa
2023-04-03 14:33:47.259 28960-28960 ActivityThread          com.android.settings                 E  Activity com.android.settings.SubSettings has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.settings.accessibility.InstalledAccessibilityService$2@7f06f04 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                                                    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.settings.SubSettings has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.settings.accessibility.InstalledAccessibilityService$2@7f06f04 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1596)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1372)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1525)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1498)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:650)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:101)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:82)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:76)
                                                                                                        at com.android.settings.accessibility.InstalledAccessibilityService.onCreate(InstalledAccessibilityService.java:3)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2515)
                                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1261)
                                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2436)
                                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2215)
                                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2171)
                                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2072)
                                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:822)
                                                                                                        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.a(SettingsActivity.java:32)
                                                                                                        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.launchSettingFragment(SettingsActivity.java:6)
                                                                                                        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:28)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3283)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2023-04-03 14:33:47.386  2741-27993 LauncherAnimationRunner com.miui.home                        E  onAnimationStart
2023-04-03 14:33:47.386  2741-27993 LauncherAnimationRunner com.miui.home                        E  onAnimationStart:   mode=0   taskId=1
2023-04-03 14:33:47.386  2741-27993 LauncherAnimationRunner com.miui.home                        E  onAnimationStart:   mode=1   taskId=6454
2023-04-03 14:33:47.386  2741-2741  QuickstepA...anagerImpl com.miui.home                        E  startClosingWindowAnimators
2023-04-03 14:33:47.386  2741-2741  ClipAnimationHelper     com.miui.home                        E  updateSourceStack  mSourceInsets=Rect(0, 101 - 0, 130), mSourceStackBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340)
2023-04-03 14:33:47.386  2741-2741  ClipAnimationHelper     com.miui.home                        E  updateHomeStack  mSourceInsets=Rect(0, 101 - 0, 130), mHomeStackBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340)
2023-04-03 14:33:47.386  2741-2741  ClipAnimationHelper     com.miui.home                        E  updateTargetRect  mSourceRect=RectF(0.0, 101.0, 1080.0, 2441.0)   mTargetRect=RectF(0.0, 0.0, 1080.0, 2340.0)   mSourceWindowClipInsets=RectF(0.0, 101.0, 0.0, 0.0)   mHomeStackBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340)   targetRect=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340)
2023-04-03 14:33:47.387  2741-2741  QuickstepA...anagerImpl com.miui.home                        E  startClosingWindowAnimators:startRect=RectF(0.0, 0.0, 1080.0, 2340.0), targetRect=Rect(840, 841 - 989, 990), currentRotation=0, isUseSimpleAnim=false
2023-04-03 14:33:47.387  2741-2741  FloatingIconView        com.miui.home                        E  recycle
2023-04-03 14:33:47.392  2741-2741  QuickstepA...anagerImpl com.miui.home                        E  startLauncherContentAnimator:isAppOpening=false
2023-04-03 14:33:47.398  2741-3069  VariableElement         com.miui.home                        E  fail to create array:iconAni
2023-04-03 14:33:47.423  2741-3069  ResourceLoader          com.miui.home                        E  fail to get getPathForLanguage: den480/quietImage.png
2023-04-03 14:33:47.423  2741-3069  ResourceLoader          com.miui.home                        E  fail to get getPathForLanguage: quietImage.png
2023-04-03 14:33:47.423  2741-3069  ResourceLoader          com.miui.home                        E  fail to get getPathForLanguage: den480/quietImage.png
2023-04-03 14:33:47.423  2741-3069  ResourceManager         com.miui.home                        E  fail to load image: quietImage.png
2023-04-03 14:33:47.423  2741-2868  StateBroadcastUtils     com.miui.home                        E  sendFsStateBroadCast state=closeWindow   channel=navigation_bar   packageName=
2023-04-03 14:33:47.839  2741-2741  FloatingIconView        com.miui.home                        E  recycle
2023-04-03 14:33:47.858  2741-2741  LauncherAnimationRunner com.miui.home                        E  finish: mFinishRunnable.run
2023-04-03 14:33:47.892  2741-2741  RotationHelper          com.miui.home                        E  setCurrentTransitionRequest: request=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in `context.startActivity(intent)`; I think you can use it directly  `startActivityIntent()` without that use of `context`, and for the other things, you can use timer and finishAndRemoveTask without `ActivityA.this`.

so your final code for this method may be something like the following:

```kotlin
public void timerStart() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        if (isAccessibilityEnabled()) {
          timer.cancel();
          finishAndRemoveTask();
          Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          return;
        }
      }
    }, 0, 500);
  }
```

If the issue still remains, consider may be moving the `startActivity(intent)` before `finishAndRemoveTask()` method; although I don't think it is not an issue try it anyways!

Comment: I made the changes and, as activity A was the only one on the stack, after the finishAndRemoveTask() the app is closed and activity B still hasn't started.

Comment: Can you share with us the full code?

Comment: updated with full code

Comment: Believe it or not, I just used your code and it is working fine, I mimicked a version of our isAccessbilityEnabled(), and it is going normally to the second activity! Your code is correct!

Comment: Very strange. I made a change to the post and added a print with the sequence of screens that occur. Note that at the end, the application is completely closed instead of moving on to the next activity.

Comment: I updated the post with the error that occurs in Logcat right after granting permission